# Bug? While trying to review first time question

Tags: bug, review-queues

So the issue happened in all 3 major browsers (!IE) and with cleared cookies.

While trying to review it says one number, but when going inside it says this queue has been cleared; is this a known bug?

List of available questions for review:
[image: Screenshot]

Result after going for it:
[image: Screenshot]

Tested in all browsers with private (incognito mode) – same result.

Comment: This is a caching issue. If you wait a moment and refresh the page, the numbers should correct themselves.

Comment: that is what I thought, but you mean local or server caching? I did try it a different browsers

Comment: server caching.

Comment: @jycr753 It's cached on SE's side because it would previously calculate how many posts were available *for you*, which is a lot of server load.

Comment: @AstroCB Cool thanks, i will be removing this question them, because I don't think it will be that useful, right?

Comment: @jycr753 You can leave it; a web of duplicates helps capture searches and leads back to the canonical question.